# valgrind compilation for ppc says cannot execute binary file

Tags: valgrind

Trying to run valgrind on my application.
I have copied the valgrind executable file (based on ppc compiler) into a machine based on intel compiler(i686).
I am stuck after this . 
I have tried googling for the same but did not come across any standard document.
Can anybody please help? Just a nudge in the right direction ....

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you are trying to run a valgrind compiled for PPC on an x86 machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of my processes running on PPC machine crashed. Wanted to check for memory leaks in that process. But the available valgrind is for x86 machine.